# Can you distribute a complement to sums in boolean logic?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is it correct at all to say NOT(A+B) = NOT(A)+NOT(B)?

But if that isn't true, then what is NOT(NOT(A+B)) with De Morgan's theorem?

Comment: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). It's not at all hard to disprove your own first statement. Lay it out and you should see that it doesn't work. I suspect you know that much. Just guessing, but is it that you cannot actually read the wiki description and understand it?

Comment: I find your comment too condescending to engage a conversation from, so I will wait for someone who is genuinely interested in answering questions.

Comment: Have you tried to put together a truth table?  While there are more elegant ways of solving problems, a 4 line 3 column truth table is pretty fast to pound out.

Comment: @james Sorry. But it really is very easy to disprove the first statement by a very simple table example. This leads me to wonder about whether or not you can read a short and simple description. I can't help that curiosity. It simply is there to see, is all. I really am simply curious about it. Mostly, because I wonder how it should be written to get it across. Not because I'm trying to be critical. So you misunderstood me. But that's fine. There's no requirement for anything here. Best wishes.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your arbitrary personal opinion is that something is easy relative to your experience, this is a logic question, not a political poll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT(A+B) is a NOR (**N**OT **OR**)

With De Morgan's theorem it can turn into

NOT(A) AND NOT(B)

But it's easier to visualize everything if you just use bars over the variables as "NOT". This way you can never forget De Morgan's theorem.

---

Here's your question in another format:

> Is it correct at all to say \$\overline{A+B} = \overline{A}+\overline{B}\$? But if that isn't true, then what is \$\overline{\overline{A+B}}\$ with De Morgan's theorem?

Now here's a "graphical" theorem. You can turn a \$\overline{+}\$ into a AND. You can turn a \$\overline{\text{AND}}\$ into \$+\$.

In words it would be "Break bars that has an AND gate between them, and turn them into an OR gate. Break bars that has an OR gate between them, and turn them into an AND gate. "

Likewise you can turn a broken bar that has an AND gate between them into a joined bar that has an OR gate between them. And same thing with broken bar that has an OR gate between them into a joined bar that has an AND gate between them.

---

Here's an example of your two equations:

\$\overline{A+B} = \bar A\bar B~~~~\$ The \$\bar +\$ broke the bar above it and turned itself to an AND.

\$
\begin{align}
\overline{\overline{A+B}} &= \overline{\bar A\bar B}~~~~~~\text{Turn $\bar{+}$ into an AND}
\\&= \bar{\bar{A}} +\bar{\bar{B}}~~\text{Turn $\overline{\text{AND}}$ into a +}
\\&= A + B~~\text{Remove double negative}
\end{align}
\$

[Everything is right here...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering)

Answer (score 0):

here it is laid out

as you can see, `NOT(A+B)` does not equal `NOT(A)+NOT(B)`

```
A   B   A+B   NOT(A+B)  NOT(A)   NOT(B)  NOT(A)+NOT(B) 

0   0    0       1        1        1        1
0   1    1       0        1        0        1
1   0    1       0        0        1        1
1   1    1       0        0        0        0
```

i have no idea why you are thinking that it somehow relates to NOT(NOT(A+B)).